Compatibility - Topological modules contra vector spaces
So Tréves in his book on topological vector spaces shows that a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on a $\textit{vector space}$ $E$ is the filter of neighbourhoods of zero compatible with the linear structure if and only if its members are balanced, absorbing, additive (all $F \in \mathcal{F}$ there is $G \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $G+G \subset F$) and closed under multiplication (all nonzero $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ ,  $\lambda F \in \mathcal{F}$).
Northcott in his book on modules gives a similar presentation for a filtered module $M$ over a ring $R$ in terms of submodules $M_{n+1} \subset M_n$  and claims that addition $\cdot + \cdot $ and multiplication $r \ \cdot$ are continuous operations under the topology induced by the base of neighbourhoods $x + M_n$ around a given point $x \in M$, and does this with ease. Why does this work?
Tréves even points to the ring of formal power series and the descending sequence of ideals $M_{n+1}$ of formal power series whose first $n$ coefficients are all zero but for which the induced topology is not compatible with multiplication unless $\mathbb{C}$ identifies with elements in $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$.
And how do the compatibility conditions for modules compare to those of vector spaces?
Edit: So he (Northcott) seems to consider maps $\mu_r: E \mapsto E$ for a given $r \in R$, and he does not seem to specify any topology on $R$, so different then. In fact, he proceeds with filtered rings and filtered modules over filtered rings and comments on the multiplicative structure later on. See also: A submodule filtration that does not define the structure of topological module.
